# WebClient times out after 240s with no reason

Tags: .net, proxy, timeout, webrequest

On my development PC I have a strange problem with .NET web classes. WebClient or WebRequest http "GET"s to non-localhost addresses often do not work after process start. The download blocks for exactly 240 seconds and then timeouts. The server does not seem to see any connection attempt. Not only other PCs have no problem, even non-.net applications on the same PC do not have this problem! After some attempts in a process the problem is self-healing for that process, but reappears immediately for new process.
setting

```
request.Proxy = null
```

helps, although there is no proxy configured in internet settings! Output of: netsh winhttp show proxy

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

I checked also "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework(64)\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config"
but the only lines with "proxy" are:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

I cannot set proxy to null because I also use third-party .net components which I cannot change.
here a small powershell script which demostrate the problem. It first uses curl to demonstrate that the server connection is fine, and then tries WebRequest:

```
$url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
$TOOLS = "D:\Work\Main\Tools"

$responseText = $null
$time = measure-command { $responseText = (& $TOOLS\curl -y 30 -Y 1 -f $url) }
if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) { write-host "exit code is $lastexitcode" }
Write-Host "      Curl took $($time.TotalSeconds) to complete"
Write-Host $($responseText[0].Substring(0,35))


$responseText = $null
$time = measure-command { 
    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
#   $webRequest.Proxy = $null
    $webRequest.Timeout = 1000
    $webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000
    $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $textReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $responseStream
    $responseText = $textReader.ReadToEnd()
}
Write-Host "WebRequest took $($time.TotalSeconds) to complete"
Write-Host $($responseText[0].Substring(0,35))
```

the output is

```
      Curl took 0.1028601 to complete
<head><title>Document Moved</title>
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
At C:\Users\meyerrn\Documents\curl-vs-dotnet.ps1:18 char:5
+     $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

WebRequest took 240.0301465 to complete
```

When starting this several times in ISE, it might suddently work and then it will work until I restart ISE.
What can be wrong on my PC?

**Update:** Today the timeout time is totally random. Sometimes 240s, often less (for example 74.13, 29.76, 30.38s). WTF?

Comment: You appear not to be disposing of the response at any point. I strongly suspect that's the problem - it's hogging the connection to that host. Now whether your actual application has the same issue or not is a different matter.

Comment: The acutal application disposes. I forgot in the demonstration code, sorry. But I don't see how this would help here anyway as I cannot dispose anything before I am finished with the connection or? Then it is already too late.

Comment: Normally in my experience timeouts like this occur because the request for some reason wasn't completed, whether because it advertised a response length with the Content-Length header and didn't send that many bytes, or because it advertised Transfer-Encoding: chunked, and didn't send a final 0 chunk.  You may need to look at what your client is receiving using a packet sniffer, e.g. wireshark